# Visual Studio account checker

Tags: authentication, account

I'm trying to make a account checker in Visual Studio, like when I type my username and my password in program to check if my account is valid on this site https://www.tribalwars.net/premium.php . Can someone help me with that, I'm a beginner and I don't know how to start.

Comment: Why can't you check on the site directly? What's the end purpose of what you're trying to achieve? People are not supposed to type their passwords anywhere other than the relevant site, except if you're affiliated with it (for obvious security reasons). [Look what happened with third-party Snapchat apps](http://www.theverge.com/2014/10/10/6956725/third-party-snapchat-app-leaks-13gb-of-user-photos)...

Comment: Because I want to learn lol, I have a project and I need to do a lot of this things.